# Netsuite journal entry update issue for more than 1000 rows Suite talk API

Tags: netsuite, suitetalk

I am trying to update a journal entry on Netsuite using SuiteTalk API having more than 1000 records and getting bellow eeror -:

**Journal Entries can have a maximum of 1000 lines**
Is there any way to solve this issue,or update journal entry have more than 1000 items.
Thanks,
Hitesh Kumar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum number of lines per journal entry is **1,000** when using **synchronous web services** processing. With **asynchronous** web services processing, the limit is **10,000** lines.

Comment: Thanks @Wenson                                                                                                    I am using synchronous web services do i need to use asynchronous? is there any other way. I just need to update one custom field for mainline item i don't need to update any child records.